# Online service to show date in JSON format

Tags: json, web-services

I am looking for a web service that simply provides me with the current date in JSON format.

Google search brings up absolutely nothing, so I'd like to ask if you know a reliable one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the one, this returns time in plain text in UTC.

http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now

This will return time in JSON format
http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now.json

You can specify various timezones in the query itself like 
http://www.timeapi.org/pdt/now will give you time in PDT timezone. There are number of other options as well specified at [homepage](http://www.timeapi.org/).

In order to get the data in JSON format like below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function myCallback(json) {
        alert(new Date(json.dateString));
      }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://timeapi.org/pdt/now.json?callback=myCallback"></script>
```

You can also have a look at
http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html and

Here is the sample [output in JSON format](http://api.geonames.org/timezoneJSON?lat=47.01&lng=10.2&username=demo).

Comment: Any idea how this http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now tells the time, like what timezone it uses? I need it to be something like based on the IP address of the requester (if thats possible)

Comment: Edited the answer for different timezones and JSON format.